# How to update angular2 components with Baobab

Tags: angularjs, angular, baobab

Baobab looks like an interesting way to build a Flux application with Angular 2 but I have not found any example.

My main question is how do I 'subscribe' an Angular Component to Baobab:

```
@Component
( { selector: 'foo'
  , template:
    ` <ul>
        <li *ngFor='#color of ( colors | async )'>
          {{ color }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    `
  }
)
export default class FooComponent {
  colorsCursor: any

  constructor ( @Inject (storeToken) private store ) {
    // https://github.com/Yomguithereal/baobab
    this.colorsCursor = store.select('palette', 'colors')

    this.colorsCursor.on
    ( 'update'
    , () => {
        // What do I put here to update the component ?
      }
    )
  }

  get colors () {
    return this.colorsCursor.get ()
  }
}
```

Or should I push the data through inputs in the component ? But I am not sure how to wire all this...

Answer (score 0):

To make the data flow clear / not modifying the tree directly from the controller, you might need a service (for actions). 
Call that from the controller to request a change, and have the controller watch for changes from the Baobab state tree.

Then, you'd have a flow like this (from http://christianalfoni.github.io/javascript/2015/02/06/plant-a-baobab-tree-in-your-flux-application.html):

```
Architecture using Baobab

            |------------|
        |-> | State tree | --|           
        |   |------------|   |
        |                    v
  |---------|         |------------|
  | Actions | <------ | Components |
  |---------|         |------------|
```

And for Angular 2 -style component hierarchy, I'd put the cursor *.on('update'...*  method in a higher level Component, and pass the values down to the child components via Inputs.

```
            |------------|
        |-> | State tree | --|           
        |   |------------|   |
        |                    v
  |---------|         |----------------|
  | Actions | <------ | Component(*)   |
  |---------|         |----------------|
                          |     ^
                       @Input  @Output (EventEmitter)
                          v     |
                      |------------------|
                      | Child Components |
                      |------------------|
```

The Component(*) acts as a controller-view in React, being close to the top, and listening for events that are broadcast by the Baobab state tree.

Also, I think using

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

in the child component might improve things as we make sure it only updates as the Inputs push the change from above.

I have an example of this at Codepen, without the Actions Service yet, though.

http://codepen.io/mikkokam/pen/zqeWmQ?editors=0010